# How to select a value with FluentLenium

Tags: scala, selenium, playframework-2.0, automated-tests

we're using [FluentLenium](https://github.com/FluentLenium/FluentLenium) via Play Framework 2.0 and can't seem to find out how you select a certain value in a dropdown on the page.  Everything else is pretty straightforward and works well.

I see some references to FluentSelect but they only seem to exist in the Java version.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to the help on #selenium on FreeNode the answer is as simple as:

its a case of finding the option, finding the value inside that and then clicking

So in this case if you put an ID on your option value it's simply:

```
browser.$("#smalloption").click()
```

Easy!